# What is the most efficient way to integrate $(x-3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I can do the problem, but it is becoming so big,that I do  not feel to do it anymore.  Can anyone give the shortest method for this problem?

$$\int (x-3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\,dx $$

Answer (score 2):

As $$x^2+3x-18=\frac{4x^2+12x-72}4=\frac{(2x+3)^2-9^2}4$$

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html), set $2x+3=9\sec\theta$

So, we have $x-3=\dfrac92(\sec\theta-1)\implies dx=\dfrac92\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$

$x^2+3x-18=\dfrac{9\tan^2\theta}4\implies\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}=\dfrac32|\tan\theta|$

$$I=\int(x-3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\ dx=\dfrac32|\tan\theta|\dfrac92(\sec\theta-1)\dfrac92\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$$

If $\tan\theta\ge0,$
$$I=\frac{3^5}8\int (\sec\theta-1)\sec\theta\tan^2\theta\ d\theta$$

$$\frac8{3^5}I=\int(\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta)\ d\theta-\int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta\ d\theta$$

$$=\int d(\tan^2\theta)-\int\sec\theta(\sec^2\theta-1)\ d\theta$$

$$=\frac{\tan^3\theta}3-\int\sec^3\theta\ d\theta+\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$

Now use [Integral of the secant function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function) and [Integral of secant cubed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)

Comment: In case of (x-3) do i have to substitute the value of x.

Comment: @user146181, We must convert $\int f(x)\ dx$ to $\int v(\theta)\ d\theta$

Comment: Can u write the expression of  v(theta)d(theta).

Comment: @user146181, Why don't you try?

Comment: I tried many times,please write the expression.

Comment: @user146181, Please find the edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Hint: substitute $x=u+3$. Then,

$$\int (x-3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\,dx =\int u\sqrt{u(u+9)}\,du$$

Comment: Can u state what to do after that.

Comment: $\int u\sqrt{u(u+9)}du = \int u^2\sqrt{\frac{u+9}{u}}du$ and now a trivial substitution ...

Comment: @user146181 Next, you could perform an Euler substitution of type 1 or type 3.

Answer (score 2):

As $\dfrac{d(x^2+3x-18)}{dx}=2x+3$

$$I=\int(x-3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\ dx,$$

$$2I=\int(2x-6)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\ dx$$
$$=\int(2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\ dx-9\sqrt{x^2+3x-18}\ dx$$

For the second integral, $x^2+3x-18=\left(x+\dfrac32\right)^2-\left(\dfrac92\right)^2,$

set $x+\dfrac32=u$ and use [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ12/integ12.html)

Comment: @user146181, I think this answer is simpler than my other answer